# Run several ant tasks on the same VM

Tags: ant, junit

I'm running unit test using ant

```
<target name="test" depends="tomcatDeploy" description="Build and run tests">
    <ant dir="${aDir}" target="test"/>
    <ant dir="${bDir}" target="test"/>
    <ant dir="${cDir}" target="test"/>
    <ant dir="${dDir}/ExtFramework"  target="test"/>
</target>
```

and I want to run them all on the same VM - otherwise I get *a lot* of overhead in the creation of the jvm & re-creation of statics and so forth.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task is what you're looking for. Assuming all of your subdirectories have a common parent, you can do something like the following:

```
<target name="test" depends="tomcatDeploy" description="Build and run tests">
    <subant target="test">
        <fileset dir="${parent}" includes="**/build.xml"/>
    </subant>
</target>
```

**EDIT**
How are you running the tests? If you are using the `junit` task, do you have `fork="yes"`? If so, that will run the tests in a new VM. Change that to `fork="no"` to run the tests in the same VM.

Comment: Isn't it the same effect like yossale's approach? Since it's the same text in the manual: "Calls a given target for all defined sub-builds. This is an extension of ant for bulk project execution. This task must not be used outside of a target if it invokes the same build file it is part of." (http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTasks/subant.html) and "Runs Ant on a supplied buildfile. This can be used to build subprojects. This task must not be used outside of a target if it invokes the same build file it is part of." (http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTasks/ant.html)

Comment: Edited answer in response to comment.

Comment: Jason, &lt;subant&gt; uses &lt;ant&gt; under the covers, so you comment about efficiency makes no sense.

Comment: Well, I really screwed that one up; antcall reparses the buildfile and runs all dependent targets, making it much slower than subant. Mea Culpa.

Answer (score 0):

The  task by itself doesn't create a new VM. Are your tests creating a new VM?

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize the problem: Does your test create a new VM if you start it manually via JUnit? Or does the problem only occur in combination with ant?
Probably it's JUnit or your tests creating a new VM and leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<parallel threadCount='4'>
  <ant target='TargetThatConsumesLotsOfCPUTimeAndMemory'>
    <param name='file' value='one.txt'/>
  </ant>
  <ant target='TargetThatConsumesLotsOfCPUTimeAndMemory'>
    <param name='file' value='two.txt'/>

  </ant>
  <ant target='TargetThatConsumesLotsOfCPUTimeAndMemory'>
    <param name='file' value='three.txt'/>
  </ant>
  <!-- repeated about 40 times -->
</parallel>
```

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/ant/how-to-use-parallel-task.html

Comment: I think he wants to do this in ONE VM?

Comment: Thanks , but I need it all to run in one VM. I did it using the "junit" task (~new ant feature) but then I ran into another problem - the local directory is set by the jvm , and if use the same one for all , I have a problem with the classpathes